# Can Route 53 Perform Failover to Pages Hosted on External Platforms?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to configure failover for a web server that uses an Application Load Balancer. When the server becomes unhealthy, I want visitors to be redirected to a maintenance page hosted on another platform. I have the maintenance page's domain name and directory (test.example.com/outage), but Route 53 tutorials usually use S3 for hosting. Is it necessary to host the maintenance page on S3, or can it be hosted on other instances?

Comment: Why is your system using an Application Load Balancer? Does this mean that you have multiple Amazon EC2 instances running?

Comment: S3 hosting is dirt cheap and so easy to hook up a outage page. Also S3 has copies of the data and is hosted in multiple AZs so your DR is built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Route 53 can perform Health Checks on your site.

If a health check fails, it can change the DNS resolution (eg going to a different IP address or domain name). However, DNS **only resolves a domain name to an IP address**. It cannot forward people to a specific page on another host (eg `/outage`).

See: [Creating Amazon Route 53 health checks and configuring DNS failover - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html)